# Virtual host being redirected to https://adminboard.app in google chrome

Tags: apache

I have made a virtual host adminboard.app. But the problem is when i browse this link from google chrome it redirects to https://adminboard.app which does not exist. It is working perfectly in firefox. What is the problem and how can i solve it in google chrome?

I Want the google chrome to redirect to my virtual host rather than https://adminboard.app which does not exist on the internet

Answer (score 12):

I have this trouble too after google chrome update on two PC :-(
Delete domain security policies in chrome://net-internals/#hsts did not help.
Clear all cache data did not help.
UPD: Nginx
UPD2: This error for domain *.dev. If you change *.dev to *.local then virtual host worked

Comment: As of May 2019, this issue is still here.

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this issue. We just have to mention virtual host with .test extension and it will work.Google chrome 63 update

Comment: *.local works too, as mentioned by @AlexanderLapenko