# Virtual host blocked on Chrome with Privacy Error

Tags: apache, google-chrome, xampp, virtualhost

I'm using my localhost `xampp` with `Apache`, ports 80, 443. I've configured `virtual host` for my local application through some domain name, Recently `chrome` got updated to `Version 63.0.3239.84` and while fetching the application it is throwing Privacy Error:

[image: Virtual Host error]

And while fetching the directly from the local host url, like `localhost/phpmyadmin` it opens the page:

[image: phpmyadmin]

I followed [localhost blocked on Chrome with "Privacy Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35531347/localhost-blocked-on-chrome-with-privacy-error) and tried configuring as suggested which was already enabled

[image: Allow localhost]

Help me out with this.

Comment: In the question you link to, they are running on `localhost`, not some random internet TLD.

Comment: @JoshLee please check the error screenshot, it is working on localhost only, it's just i'm using virtual host of apache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed by changing my vhost from *.dev to *.local.

See [Virtual host being redirected to https://adminboard.app in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732219/virtual-host-being-redirected-to-https-adminboard-app-in-google-chrome)